# Pass Function result as an element of an array within a For Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm having a really hard time adding this small function to my work here:

Basically if data[i][49] is blank I want to assign my name "Clay" to it and otherwise data[i][49]. I've tried putting it in multiple places and it just inserts the whole function body into my spreadsheet.

Thanks for any help!

```
var whywontthiswork = (function {if(data[i][49] == " "){

         "Clay"


         }else{

         data[i][49]

         };})
```

It keeps saying "Invalid property ID. (line 27, file "C1: Push Load Details")"

```
function pushLoadDetails() {

  deleteCSV();

  //allPlainTextFormat(); adds 20 seconds

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sh0 = ss.getSheetByName("Loads"), sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("DAT"), sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Truckstop"), 
      sh3 = ss.getSheetByName("Posteverywhere"),sh4 = ss.getSheetByName("Push"), sh5 = ss.getSheetByName("Carriers");


  // get data from Loads sheet
  var data = sh0.getRange(8,4,33,55).getValues();

  // create array to hold data (imaginary)
  var aMain = new Array(); 
  var bMain = new Array();
  var myArray = aMain;

  // itterate through data and add to array

  //for (var i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++) {}


  for(var i=0; i < 31; i++) {   //Controls how many rows it goes through for posting  //  len = data.length; i < len

  var whywontthiswork = (function {if(data[i][49] == " "){

     "Clay"


     }else{

     data[i][49]

     };})


        if(i != ""){




    for(var j=25; j<28; j++) {                //Controls which date elements to iterate through for posting




    for(var k=32; k<37; k++) {                //Controls which trailer type elements to iterate through for posting





     var aPushArray =  [data[i][0],data[i][1],data[i][2],data[i][3],data[i][4],data[i][5],data[i][6],data[i][7],data[i][8],data[i][9],
      data[i][10],data[i][11],data[i][12],data[i][13],data[i][14],data[i][15],data[i][16],data[i][17],data[i][18],data[i][19],
      data[i][20],data[i][21],data[i][22],data[i][23],data[i][24],data[i][j],//data[i][25],//data[i][26],data[i][27],
      data[i][28],data[i][29],
      data[i][30],data[i][31],data[i][k],//data[i][32],data[i][33],data[i][34],data[i][35],data[i][36],
      data[i][37],data[i][38],data[i][39],
      data[i][40],data[i][41],data[i][42],data[i][43],data[i][44],data[i][45],
      data[i][46],data[i][47],data[i][48],[whywontthiswork]//data[i][49]
      ]
      //[Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+8", "ddMMyyyyHHmmssSSS")] can go over data[i][44] to make consecutive numbers

   //var aJK = Logger.log(aPushArray[0].length); 
   //var aWidth = return aJK;


   //ts = aPushArray.split(',');






    var aPush = aMain.push(aPushArray); //add more data sets to import more columns of data


    };



    };
    };
  };

// function pushCarrierInfo(){ 
  for(var i=0; i < 31; i++) {  

     if(i != ""){                  //Controls how many rows it goes through for posting
                                   //Controls which trailer type elements to iterate through for posting

    deleteSheet("Carriers","A2:AZ")

    var bPush = bMain.push(
     [data[i][49],data[i][46],data[i][48],data[i][47],
     data[i][0],data[i][1],data[i][2],data[i][3],data[i][4],data[i][5],data[i][6],data[i][7],data[i][8],//data[i][9],
      //data[i][10],data[i][11],data[i][12],data[i][13],data[i][14],data[i][15],data[i][16],data[i][17],data[i][18],
      data[i][19],
      //data[i][20],data[i][21],data[i][22],data[i][23],data[i][24],data[i][25],data[i][26],data[i][27],
      data[i][28],data[i][29],
      data[i][30],data[i][31],//data[i][32],data[i][33],data[i][34],data[i][35],data[i][36],
      data[i][37],data[i][38],data[i][39],
      data[i][40],data[i][41],data[i][42],data[i][43],data[i][44],data[i][45]//,data[i][46],data[i][48],data[i][49],
      //data[i][50],data[i][51],data[i][52],data[i][53]                                    
      ]); //add more data sets to import more columns of data

    };
  };
//  };


  //var aWidth = Logger.log(aPushArray[0].length);
  //var bWidth = Logger.log(bPush[0].length);

  // add array of data to second sheet. final column length must match # of data sets
  sh4.getRange(2, 1, aMain.length, 44).setValues(aMain);
  sh5.getRange(2, 1, bMain.length, 27).setValues(bMain);








deleteSheet("Posteverywhere","A3:Z")

  //allPlainTextFormat(); adds 20 seconds
  //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var ssk = SpreadsheetApp.openById("15bdmuKR9aHZyjffpzN0wFqhnJf6klFmni64OnA3HEEo");

  var shk = ssk.getSheetByName("Posteverywhere");


  var thissheet = ss.getSheetByName("Posteverywhere"); //row, column, numRows, numColumns
  //var thissheet = thisSheet.getRange(4,1,50,30); 

  // get data from Loads sheet
  var dataK = shk.getRange(1,1,34,52).getValues();


  //create array to hold data (imaginary)

  var koturMain = new Array();



  // itterate through data and add to array  
  for(var i=0; i < 31; i++) {  

     if(i != ""){                  //Controls how many rows it goes through for posting
                                   //Controls which trailer type elements to iterate through for posting


    var koturPE = koturMain.push([dataK[i][0],dataK[i][1],dataK[i][2],dataK[i][3],dataK[i][4],dataK[i][5],dataK[i][6],dataK[i][7],dataK[i][8],dataK[i][9],
      dataK[i][10],dataK[i][11],dataK[i][12],dataK[i][13],dataK[i][14],dataK[i][15],dataK[i][16],dataK[i][17],dataK[i][18],dataK[i][19],
      dataK[i][20],dataK[i][21],dataK[i][22],dataK[i][23],dataK[i][24],dataK[i][25],dataK[i][26],dataK[i][27],dataK[i][28],dataK[i][29],
      dataK[i][30],//data[i][31],//data[i][32],data[i][33],data[i][34],data[i][35],data[i][36],
      //data[i][37],data[i][38],data[i][39],
      //data[i][40],data[i][41],data[i][42],data[i][43],data[i][45],data[i][44],//data[i][46],data[i][47],data[i][48],data[i][49]
      ]); //add more data sets to import more columns of data

    };
  };




  // add array of data to second sheet. final column length must match # of data sets



 // thissheet.getRange(thissheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, koturMain.length, 25).setValues(koturMain);






};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a number of things I realized this would get the job done without increasing processing time and having to mess with formatting or inserting any functions.

Using the or "||" symbol is and if/else statement.

```
[data[i][49]||"Clay"]
```